# awk - Find and replace string from column 1 with string from column 2 in multiple files

Tags: awk

I have a txt file (strings.txt) with several sets of strings (two per line) sperated by a blank:

```
String1 String1_new

String2 String2_new
```

...

Then I have several xml files that contain the strings from column 1 (String1, String 2...). I want to replace the given strings with the _new version. I reckon I can do this with awk: search any of the strings from the first column in a file, if found: replace for the correspondin _new string, go to next file and repeat.
I'm not too familiar with awk and how to build this. Can anyone help? I found this as an initial code and I understand it is pretty incomplete for the purpose, but maybe someone can complete it? Any help is appreciated:

```
 awk -i inplace '
    NR == FNR { map[NR]=$2 }
    NR != FNR { sub(/ /,map[ARGIND]) }
    1' strings.txt ?.xml
```

Sample from the xml files to be processed, e.g. File1.xml:

```
<reference id="referenceTemplate">
  <title>String1</title> 
  </reference>
```

Sample for the output, eg. File1.xml:

```
<reference id="referenceTemplate">
  <title>String1_new</title> 
  </reference>
```

Comment: Please, post a proper sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesBrown Sorry, hope this is good!

Comment: One important piece of information is missing: where are located the strings to replace in your XML files? Anywhere, even in tag names or attributes? Only as content of the `<title>` tag? Other?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks, Renaud. Here is the locations of the string: 

<image href="../figures/filename1.png" id="id_xxx_yyy_zzz"/>

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Important note: The string to be replaced is: href="../figures/filename1.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify where, in the XML files, the strings to replace can be found. So, let's assume it is anywhere. If your `awk` supports associative arrays they are probably the easiest way:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
       map[$1] = $2
       next
     }
     {
       for(s in map)
         gsub(s, map[s])
     }
     1
' strings.txt *.xml
```

Note: the `for` loop forces an order among the strings to replace. And you do not have control on the order. However it could be that the order matters, for instance if some of your strings are sub-strings of others. If it is your case use indexed arrays instead of an associative array:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       n = 0
     }
     NR == FNR {
       str[n] = $1
       map[n++] = $2
       next
     }
     {
       for(i=0; i<n; i++)
         gsub(str[i], map[i])
     }
     1
' strings.txt *.xml
```

Note: to do the replacement in place, if you want to preserve the `strings.txt` file, you must be careful and print it without modification instead of not printing anything at all for it. Else it will be emptied. Example with the associative array:

```
awk -i inplace 'NR == FNR {
       map[$1] = $2
       print
       next
     }
     {
       for(s in map)
         gsub(s, map[s])
     }
     1
' strings.txt *.xml
```

Comment: I've tested all the codes but get "^ unterminated string" errors

Comment: Could it be that you skipped the leading single quote in the last line of each code snippet?

Comment: I didn't skip them. I even tried to replace them with double quotation marks (I work under windows and read that single quotation marks have to be replaced with double quotation marks. When I use single quot. marks I get "^ invalid char ''' in expression"

Comment: What version of `awk` do you use? And do you see the same if you put the whole `awk` program on one single line?

Comment: I've installed gawk-3.1.6-1-setup
I've tried it all in one line:

    `awk -i inplace "NR == FNR { map[$1] = $2 print next } { for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s]) } 1 " strings.txt *.xml`

but this time it gives me a "^ syntax error"

Comment: You must replace the newlines by semi-columns: `awk -i inplace "NR == FNR { map[$1] = $2; print; next } { for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s]) } 1" strings.txt *.xml`

Comment: I've tried but still get a syntax error pointing the ^ to the dot in `strings.txt`
Does awk have difficulties with this maybe?

Comment: Sorry but I do not see what the problem could be. Of course `awk` has absolutely no problems with dots in file names. There must be something else but I do not have enough information to imagine what it could be.

Comment: Yes, I think I have to give up on this and perhaps find another solution. :-/ Thank you so much for your time and help, Renaud! I can't appreciate that enough!

Comment: Oh! I think I got it. **Do not replace single quotes with double quotes**. If you do so the `$` signs in the `awk` program are expanded by the shell. Those who told you that this is needed under Windows are wrong. Try (single line): `awk 'NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2;next} {for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s])} 1' strings.txt *.xml`. And be sure to use single quotes, not backticks or whatever. Better: copy-paste exactly on one single line.

Comment: I've tried it but it still gives me the `^ invalid char'''` error for the single quotes. I've tried to run the code directly from the cmd and from an awk file with `awk -f test_awk.awk` The result is the same.

Comment: Then it is not real single quotes that you use (or your command line interface is not what you think). If you put the `awk` program in a file do not put the single quotes. Put only: `NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2;next} {for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s])} 1` and type: `awk -f test_awk.awk strings.txt *.xml`.

Comment: That did it! Script is running and processing over 1.300 files. I'll tell you about the results. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now awk processes all the files but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Sure. If you want to change the files in place you must call `awk` with the `-i -inplace` option. **BE CAREFUL**: read again the last note in my answer and add a `print` statement to preserve the `strings.txt` file: `NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2;print;next} {for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s])} 1`.

Comment: Again, it only goes through all the files, but the files remain unchanged. The strings are not replaced in the xml files.

Comment: This means that your `awk` does not support the `-i inplace` option and it does not even warn you about this (which is a bit weird). Sorry, you'll have to try something else.

Comment: By the way, in your question you show an `awk` command that uses single quotes and the `-i inplace` option. How is it that this one worked but that now you cannot use single quotes and the `-i inplace` option any more? Did you change something? What command line interface do you use? What do you see if you type `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: I can't use the single quotes at all. At the beginning, the code didn't run at all. Then I discovered the single quote problem.
This is the code I have in an .awk file, and only that code: `-i inplace NR==FNR {map[$1]=$2;print;next} {for(s in map) gsub(s, map[s])} 1` 
In the cmd line of win10, I type: awk -f test_awk.awk strings.txt *.xml
When I type echo $SHELL in cmd line, it returns $SHELL back.
It runs, but doesn't change anything (as mentioned before)

Comment: Don't put the `-i inplace` option in the `awk` script file. It is an option, not an `awk` language statement. Type `awk -i inplace -f test_awk.awk strings.txt *.xml`.

Comment: Apparently your command-line interface is some Windows-specific interface, not something I use, sorry. If you plan to use tools like `awk`, `sed` and others you should consider using another interface, the one you have looks too limited for complex tasks. Modern shells like `bash` are good candidates. I think Windows also comes with something called `PowerShell`.

Comment: OK, that was it. I used cygwin and it did the trick. Everything was replaced! The task is done. Leave me your address somehow. I owe you a good bottle of wine, Renaud. You're the best.

Comment: Good to know that it finally worked. So, you know [what to do next](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), do you?

Comment: Yep, correct answer already confirmed! But due to my rank I still can't upvote.